# In Java, why can't an array be a Type Variable's bound, but can be a Wildcard's bound?

Tags: java, arrays, wildcard, bounds, type-parameter

In Java, why can't an array be a Type Variable's bound, but can be a Wildcard's bound?

You can have:

```
List< ? extends Integer[] > l;
```

but you can't have:

```
class MyClass< T extends Integer[] > { } // ERROR!
```

Why?

Comment: It's a strange one. The JLS quite clearly states that you can only use classes or interfaces in type variables but fails to give any explanation whatsoever.

Comment: just to do like-comparisons: "List< ? extends Integer[] > k1;" is allowed, but "List< T extends Integer[] > k2;" is not. But I couldnt find anything except null to add to the list! Eclipse says k1.get(0) returns type Integer[], but I could not add one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this Java code:

```
package test;

public class Genric<E>
{
    public Genric(E c){
        System.out.println(c.getClass().getName());
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Genric<Integer[]>(new Integer[]{1,2});
    }
}
```

**For your first case:**

```
List< ? extends Integer[] > l;
```

When you do something like this `List< ? extends Integer[] > l;` then the Java compiler sees it as a  `List< ? extends Object> l;` and translates it accordingly. So this is why you don't get any error.

The generated byte-code is as follows:

```
   .
   .
   .
   20:  aastore
   21:  invokespecial   #52; //Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   24:  return
   .
   .
```

Checkout the line number **21**. Although, I have passed an array of `java.lang.Integer`; internally it is translated to `java.lang.Object`.

**For your second case:**

```
class MyClass< T extends Integer[] > { } // ERROR!
```

As per java language specification:

```
TypeParameter:
TypeVariable TypeBoundopt

TypeBound:
extends ClassOrInterfaceType AdditionalBoundListopt
.
.
```

As you can see the the bound consists solely of class or an interface (not even primitive types). So when you do something like this `class MyClass< T extends Integer[] > { }` then `Integer[]` does not qualify as a class or interface.

As per my understanding of Java Spec, this was done to solve all the scenarios like

1. `class MyClass< T extends Integer[] >`
2. `class MyClass< T extends Integer[][] >`
3. ..
4. `class MyClass< T extends Integer[][]...[] >`

Because all of them can be represented as `java.lang.Object` and when passed as parameter, as in example

```
public Genric(E c){
            System.out.println(c.getClass().getName());
        }
```

as 'c' remembers its true type.

Hope this will help.

Comment: +1 for digging into ther bytecode, although this still is more like a an explanation of "hows" rather than the "whys". Isn't the replacement of the type parameter with `Object` simply due to type erasure, and applied always? I.e. `List<T extends MyClass>` would also become a `List<Object>` in the bytecode isn't it? Generic type safety is checked only by the compiler before the type erasure happens.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to think about specific reasons this should be forbidden but the only one I can think of is that it's a completely unnecessary construct, because:

```
class Foo<T extends Integer[]> {
   T bar();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo<T extends Integer> {
   T[] bar();
}
```

Obviously the same cannot be said about the wildcard case, hence it's allowed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public class MyClass<K> {
    K array;
    public MyClass(K k) {
       array = k;
    }
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
class MyClass< T extends Integer > {
   ...make your variable MyClass[]...
}
```

Hope this helps and I'm not too far off what you were asking for.

Comment: I believe he asks "WHY" not "HOW TO ..." :(

Comment: Indeed. I'm not trying to use an array as a bound for T. Just wanted to know why this restriction is imposed.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, if you tell me how to delete this post I'll get rid of it since it's irrelevant.

Comment: You don't see a "delete" link next to "edit"? Maybe you don't have enough reputation to delete posts...